# Multithreading extended panel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runnable

I'm trying to allocate a `JPanel` that implements `Runnable` interface in a `JFrame`. I'd made this sample for interpret my idea. I want to add a multi-threading   panel that shows a text as demo to a window with a `String` as parameter of a new instance. The panel should have independent process so I implemented `Runnable` interface. But when I try to create a new instance o panel with a new instance of my class, It doesn't work.

What I am doing wrong?

imagePanel Panel class:

```
public class imagePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    JLabel imageTest;

    public imagePanel(String textLabel)
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        imageTest = new JLabel(textLabel);
        imageTest.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    }

    public void setImageText(String newText){
        imageTest.setText(newText);
    }

    public void run(){
        this.add(imageTest);
    }

}
```

Main class test class:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));            

        JPanel panel = new imagePanel("Text label");
        panel.setPreferredSize(frame.getPreferredSize());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very pretty to create a "multithreaded panel". Panel is a user interface component, it shouldn't do anything with threads. Also in your code `run()` will never be called, so it's "broken" too.

Comment: You've forget to add label to your panel

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy While the example posted certainly won't add the label, assuming they've create a `Thread` which wraps the instance of `panel` at some point in their actual code, `this.add(imageTest);` should get called ... but that's a lot of "if"s

Comment: Sorry this is just a sample of what I'm trying do work that I'd wrote it fast, I'm working with face recognition with camera using Opencv APIs, need a independient process for that class and show directly in panel.

Comment: Re: "a JPanel that implements Runnable" Sounds like a clear violation of the Single Responsibility Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 2):

1. Swing is not thread safe, meaning updates to the UI should only be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution
2. Swing layouts are lazy, which is a good thing, they won't update till you tell them (or some other event requires them to update, for example, the container is resized). You can trigger an update by calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you are updating
3. Creating a new instance of class doesn't magically connect all the instances you might have, that would make the program rather difficult to manage

Answer (score 1):

there several things missing

**VERY IMPORTANT** - you should not update UI in other than the AWT EventDispatcher threads. Using Swing it even may lead to deadlocks. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572726/java-awt-threads)

you have to use the SwingUtilities to update the Swing UI components.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // update your UI components
    }
});
```

Next information - How you create a multi-threaded thread? What you miss is the entry point to run your "run" method:

```
public class MyMultiThreadedType implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // this will run in parallel
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyMultiThreadedType mmt = new MyMultiThreadedType ();
    Thread t = new Thread(mmt);
    t.start(); // this will start a parallel thread
  } 
}
```